# How to execute Jquery code only once??

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, padding

I have one jquery method and i used call that method on click of a button .
So in that code i have one line " `$("#loadingMessage").css('padding-top','6%');` "   i need this line execute only once when we call that method first time,later that i gone this line .

So please help me to find one way

the entire method script is below

```
$('#SearchButton').click(function() {                 
         $(".spinner").css('visibility','hidden');

         $("#loadingMessage").css('padding-top','6%'); //I want this line execute only once, i mean first time

         loaderStart();
         document.getElementById('loadinggif3').style.display = "block";
         $("#loadinggif3").show();
         $(".col-sm-9").css('visibility','hidden');
          var str = $('#SearchText').val();
          str = str.trim();
         if(str=="") return false;
        )};
```

Comment: Please provide fiddle.

Comment: You can use a hidden field and use it as counter.

Comment: if you put a named function to click handler, then inside the named function you can unbind the handler

Comment: i didnt understand about hidden field?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [jQuery .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/). When using .one() method, the event handler function is only run once for each element.

```
$('#SearchButton').one("click", function () {
    $("#loadingMessage").css('padding-top', '6%');
});

$('#SearchButton').click(function () {
    $(".spinner").css('visibility', 'hidden');

    loaderStart();
    document.getElementById('loadinggif3').style.display = "block";
    $("#loadinggif3").show();
    $(".col-sm-9").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    var str = $('#SearchText').val();
    str = str.trim();
    if (str == "") return false;
});
```

Comment: i'd rather work it out with conditional statements than binding two event handlers on the same element.

Comment: @frosdqy how can we apply this technique in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435451/on-resize-trigger-funciton-once-till-the-condition-is-true-or-false

Answer (score 17):

Use a boolean as a global variable, like

```
var flag = true;
```

Now, set the condition before the execution, Like

```
if(flag){  
   $("#loadingMessage").css('padding-top','6%');  
   flag=false;  
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to restrict #SearchButton click event to fire only once, use `.one` method

```
$('#SearchButton').one('click', function() {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

quick and 'dirty' solution:

```
$.first_time = true;
$('#SearchButton').click(function() {                 
    if($.first_time == true) $("#loadingMessage").css('padding-top','6%');
    $.first_time = false;
});
```

some explanation: you need a global `jQuery` variable here (`$.first_time` in this example), so that it's still known inside the anonymous function of the click event.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to run only once a generic function without a particular event binding then use this.

```
$(document).one('ready', function(){
   // your code
   $("#id").on("click", function() {
        // other code
   });
});
```

Useful if inside a function that is called many times (prevents onclick event from beein fired many times)

Answer (score 2):

use .one for once and use click for others.check below

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#SearchButton').one('click', function() {
         $("#loadingMessage").css('padding-top','6%'); //I want this line execute only once, i mean first time

    });    


$('#SearchButton').click(function() {                 
         $(".spinner").css('visibility','hidden');


         loaderStart();
         document.getElementById('loadinggif3').style.display = "block";
         $("#loadinggif3").show();
         $(".col-sm-9").css('visibility','hidden');
          var str = $('#SearchText').val();
          str = str.trim();
         if(str=="") return false;
        });


  } ); 

       </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use js closure to slove the question.

```
function once(func) {
    let isExeced = false;
    return function(...arg) {
        if (isExeced) return void 0;
        isExeced = true;
        func.apply(null, arg)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a check around it that checks the padding-top. If it is not 6%, you need to set it. If it is, you skip the line. Tip: put the result of $('#loadingMessage') in a variable so you do not have to do a second element lookup.

Like so (not tested):

```
$('#SearchButton').click(function() {                 
    var $loadMsg = $("#loadingMessage");

    if($loadMsg.css('padding-top') !== '6%'){
         $loadMsg.css('padding-top', '6%');
    }
});
```

This is of course assuming that you want to execute the rest of the code in the click handler every time. Otherwise you can just unbind the click after the handler has been executed. Tip: use the jQuery on() and off() methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bolean in all languages.

in jquery:

```
var isFirst = true;

if(isFirst){  
$("#loadingMessage").css('padding-top','6%');  
isFirst=false;  
}
```