# On resize trigger funciton once till the condition is True or False

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to find the solution, need some help please: This is the simple example:

```
function ifTrueInitiateOnce() {
  console.log("True function should be initiated/triggered Once");
}

function ifFalseInitiateOnce() {
  console.log("False function should be initiated/triggered Once");
}

$(window).resize(function () {  
  if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    ifTrueInitiateOnce()
  } else {
  ifFalseInitiateOnce()
});
```

Here is the detailed code, I am trying to fix:

```
var enteredMobileView = false;
var enteredDesktopView = false;

var delay = (function () {
  var timer = 0;
  return function (callback, ms) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

function getWinSize() {
  if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    enteredDesktopView = true;
    enteredMobileView = false;
  } else {
    enteredDesktopView = false;
    enteredMobileView = true;
  }
}

getWinSize();

$(window).resize(function () {
  delay(function () {

    getWinSize();

  }, 500);
});

if (enteredDesktopView) {
  enteredDesktopView = false;
  ifDesktopInitiateOnce();
}

if (enteredMobileView) {
  enteredMobileView = false;
  ifMobileInitiateOnce()
}

function ifDesktopInitiateOnce() {
  console.log("DESKTOP True function should be initiated/triggered Once");
}

function ifMobileInitiateOnce() {
  console.log("MOBILE True function should be initiated/triggered Once");
}
```

I am not getting it quite right or may be making in more complex. What I am trying to get out of this code is. Once the screen get into mobile view or desktop view, while RESIZING the window, if reached to mobile size then trigger the function only once and again window resize from desktop to mobile then trigger the function only once and do the same when resized for desktop size.

Comment: Just create variable with false value which will be true after first call. Then if variable is true, don't call the funtion. Simple

Comment: @instead I tried to do just like what you said, but its' resize event and I am not sure how to fix it. I have added more code to make you understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    if (typeof(desktop) == "undefined") {
      desktop = true;
      mobile = undefined;
      console.log("DESKTOP True function should be initiated/triggered Once")
    }
  } else {
    if (typeof(mobile) == "undefined") {
      mobile = true;
      desktop = undefined;
      console.log("MOBILE True function should be initiated/triggered Once")
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Funtions that should be triggered once, should be called in resize function. I added in comment `getWinSize()` because You said that You want to call function only when someone really resize. If it should be called on page load then uncomment it.

```
function desktopFunction() {
  console.log("True function should be initiated/triggered Once");
}

function mobileFunction() {
  console.log("False function should be initiated/triggered Once");
}

var enteredMobileView = enteredDesktopView = false,
    delay = (function () {
      var timer = 0;

      return function (callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
      };
    })();

function getWinSize() {

  if ($(window).width() > 767) {

    if(! enteredDesktopView){
        desktopFunction();
        enteredDesktopView = true;
        enteredMobileView = false;
    }

  } else {

    if(! enteredMobileView){
        mobileFunction();
        enteredMobileView = true;
        enteredDesktopView = false;
    }

  }

}

// getWinSize();

$(window).resize(function () {
  delay(function () {
    getWinSize();
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: thanks for giving it a try, but Kratik's code is doing what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var win = (function() {
    var resize;
    var view;
    var enteredDesktopView;
    var enteredMobileView;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("winresize");
        return object;
    }

    function getWinSize() {
        if ($(window).width() > 767) {
            enteredDesktopView = true;
            enteredMobileView = false;
        } else {
            enteredDesktopView = false;
            enteredMobileView = true;
        }
        view = {
            "desktopView": enteredDesktopView,
            "mobileView": enteredMobileView
        };
    }



    return {
        checkResize: function() {
            if (!resize) {
                resize = createInstance();
                getWinSize();
            }
            return resize;
        }

    };
})();

function run() {
    win.checkResize();
    console.log(win.view);
}

run();
```

Comment: Does it work? Where are the functions that should be called once?