# Automatic colon in time field in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following requirement, in time field of form should add colon automatically on fly if not key manually in this format hh:mm:ss

I have below code and it works fine for fulling automatic, but if user key colon manually it is adding two colon like hh::m:ss

Can someone help with this issue?

**JSP:**

```
<b:form-group label="${runtime}" labelFor="runtime" cssLabel="col-sm-2" cssBody="col-sm-2" cssClass="required">
    <form:input path="runTime" cssClass="form-control" required="required" maxlength="8"/>
    <form:errors path="runTime" cssClass="validate-error"/>
</b:form-group>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#runTime').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode != 8 && (this.value.length === 2 || this.value.length === 5)) {
        this.value += ":";
    }
});
```

**Update Answer**

We have to add extra check before collapse with **chiliNUT** answer, else select all and hitting delete/backspace button is not working in chrome browser.

```
$('#runTime').on('keydown', function(e) {
    //your code
    if(e.keyCode != 8 && (this.value.length === 2 || this.value.length === 5)) {
        this.value += ":";
    }
    //collapse double colons
    if(this.value.endsWith("::")) {
        this.value=this.value.replace(/:+/g,":");
    }
});
```

Comment: I would turn off auto-submit and then in the click handler format your time. That way you can get rid of the keydown handler. Trying to manage through a keydown handler is a major headache.

Comment: you see this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076422/how-to-execute-jquery-code-only-once

Comment: Its not problem with double execution, somehow i need to avoid colon entry from keyboard. It should always added by script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collapse double colons after keydown

```
$('#runTime').on('keydown', function(e) {
    //your code
    if(e.keyCode != 8 && (this.value.length === 2 || this.value.length === 5)) {
        this.value += ":";
    }
    //collapse double colons
    this.value=this.value.replace(/:+/g,":");
});
```

That last line will look at the string, then take any instance of 1 or more colons (contiguous colons? :-))  and turn it into a single colon

Comment: If you perform the action on the 'keyup' -event instead, double colon will be corrected directly after typed. If you put it on the 'keydown' it will not detect the multiple colons until the next key press...

Comment: @JesperWilfing Why does your comment end in "...", did you have more to add?